# Labelling/tagging windows files

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, file-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to find a tag based file manager?](https://superuser.com/questions/78473/where-to-find-a-tag-based-file-manager)

Anybody knows of a system that adds full support of file labelling / tagging to windows (vs the specific-file-types-restricted labelling in windows 7)

Windows features that I missed, recommendations for standalone software, or even other OSs are all welcome.

Thank you

Gidi

Comment: The question this is marked as a duplicate of is dead.

Answer (score 2):

> Anybody knows of a system that adds full support of file labelling / tagging to windows

[Tabbles](http://tabbles.net/) does that and a lot more, check out the various links under the "What is it?" menu.

Answer (score 2):

I recently found [XYPlorer](http://www.xyplorer.com/product.htm) (€29.95 or €49.95, trial version available), which has support for file tagging:

> With version 9.90 XYplorer offers tagging as a radically new approach to file management and alternative to the hierarchical tree-based file management. You can assign any number of tags to any file or folder. Yes, any file, not just media files.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i think you are looking for: http://lunarfrog.com/