# Tool/code/extension for tagging files

Tags: windows-7, file-management, windows-search, tags

There are a lot of articles on how you can tag files in Windows 7, such as: http://lifehacker.com/#!232891/tag-files-and-save-searches-in-windows-vista

Furthermore there are some tools like [LunarFrog](http://lunarfrog.com/), [Tabbles](http://tabbles.net/) etc, where you can tag all the files on your system, but the tags are not saved within the files themselves.

I'm searching for a tool or some code where I have a user interface to tag the files themselves for later use with Windows Search (Windows 7).

This is my preferred way to organize my files because doing so:

- I am independent from any vendor
- I can combine search and tag functionality

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/182995/labelling-tagging-windows-files

Comment: Thanks, but I have already seen this article, but unfortunately LunarFrog & Tabbles are not the solution for the question above ...